# Finite ring with unity has $ab=1_R\implies ba=1_R$ for $a,b\in R$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, alternative-proof

Our prof gave us the following problem as an exercise:

> Suppose $(R,+,\cdot)$ is a *finite* ring with unity (denoted $1_R$) such that for some $a,b\in R$, we have $ab=1_R$
>
> Show that $ba=1_R$

Here's my attempt at a proof:

*Proof.*

Let us assume that $ba\neq 1_R$

Next, we consider $S:=\{(ba)^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z^+\}\subseteq R$

Since $R$ is a finite ring, we must have that $(ba)^m=(ba)^n$ for some distinct $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ (wlog say $m\gt n$). Then, we have $(ba)^{m-n}=1_R$

Note that $m\gt n$, so $m-n$ is a positive integer but $m-n\neq 1$ (hence $\gt 1$) since $ba\neq 1_R$ by assumption.

Now,

$$(ba)^{m-n}=1_R\iff b(ab)^{m-n-1}a=1_R\iff b(1_R)^{m-n-1}a=1_R\iff ba=1_R$$

which gives us a contradiction.

---

Is the above proof correct? I'd like the community to proofread it.

I'd also be interested in a shorter argument to prove the claim (if there is one). Thanks!

Comment: How do you go from $(ba)^m=(ba)^n$ to $(ba)^{m-n}=1$ (assuming that $m>n$)?

Comment: In fact $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$ in any left (or right) Noetherian ring.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, You're right. $R$ might not necessarily be a division ring, so my argument fails. Is there a way to fix the argument? I'd be very interested in just a hint. Thanks!

Comment: On the chance you want to learn more about rings with this property, google "Dedekind finite ring" and/or "directly finite ring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a$ has a right inverse, right multiplication by $a$, $\cdot a : R\to R$ is bijective. Thus $(\cdot a)^n=\mathrm{id}_R$ for some integer $n$. Since $(\cdot a)^n = \cdot (a^n)$, this implies that $a^n = 1_R\cdot a^n = 1_R$. Thus $b=a^nb = a^{n-1}(ab)=a^{n-1}$, so $ba=a^n=1_R$.